# JQuery using Json to call Controller/Action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a search page where the top of the page is search criteria with a search button.   The bottom of the screen is the results from when the search button is pressed.   In this case I have 6 different search criteria the user can input.   I would like to bundle all the criteria into one class so my Controller action can read the Json object as a class.   Using FireBug I am able to see my Json is built correctly.   Using the debugger I know that my Controller/Action is getting fired.  However when I look at the class object with the debugger in the Controller/Action,  all the properties are null or zero.

> **Controller**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult GetStudentByCritera(StudentSearchCriteraCV critera)
{
    // Get the Data 
    ViewData["MainData"] = studentBLLHdl.StudentFind(critera);
    return View();
}
```

> **JavaScript/JQuery**

```
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: "GetStudentByCritera",
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataToSend,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        beforeSend: ClientSideValidate,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.Result);
            $('#SearchResult').html(result.Result).show();
            // UnBlock UI
        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // UnBlock UI

            // not sure how to handel error
            alert("error happen when posting to 'GetStudentByCritera'")

            // typically only one of textStatus or errorThrown
            // will have info
            this; // the options for this ajax request
        }


    });

    function BuildJson() {
        // building Json

        var dataForClass = {
            "StudentSearchCriteraCV": [{
                "StudLname": $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudLname']").val(),
                "StudFname": $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudFname']").val(),
                "Ssn": $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.Ssn']").val(),
                "StudId": $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudId']").val(),
                "Sex": $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.Sex']").val(),
                "Race": $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.Race']").val()
            }]
        };

        return $.toJSON(dataForClass);
    }

    function ClientSideValidate() {
        // Block the UI
        alert("In the ClientSideValidate");

        // if error UNBlock UI
        // return true if client side data is good.

        return true;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your ajax call is just an asynchronous HTTP post, therefore the data paramter can only be key value pairs, not a JSON object. If you flatten dataForClass it will work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create an action filter inheriting from ActionFilterAttribute. Take a look here http://forums.asp.net/t/1237429.aspx or here http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/BlogDetail.aspx?BlogId=863 for more details on how to build this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your JSON value needs to be in quotes, unless it is a number.

```
"StudFname": '"' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudFname']").val() + '"',
```

I haven't used .toJSON(), but I believe that it turns your JSON object into a String.  Since you're creating your object just to turn it into a string right away, why not create it as a string to begin with?  That's what I did when I ran into this problem (debugger showing zeros for values.)

```
var dataForClass = '{ "StudentSearchCriteraCV" : [{ ' +
        '"StudLname": "' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudLname']").val() + '", ' +
        '"StudFname": "' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudFname']").val() + '", ' +
        '"Ssn": "' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.Ssn']").val() + '", ' +
        '"StudId": ' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.StudId']").val() + ', ' + //assuming StudID is a number
        '"Sex": "' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.Sex']").val() + '", ' +
        '"Race": "' + $("input[name='StudentSearchCriteraCV.Race']").val() +'" ' +
        '}]}';
```